# Options to anchor a printer stand or metal shelf to the wall?

Tags: drywall-anchor, shelf

I just bought a new 3d printer and because it's very high speed it's shaking its table a lot. The table is basically a printer stand with metal square sides and two wood shelfs. I added metal aluminum strips crossing the back for added stability and that was good enough for the old printer, but the new one shakes everything around a lot more. I am going to be moving this to a new location and possibly a new table/shelf. My idea is to attach the legs to the wall by driving screws through the leg with a big washer and into a stud. I'm pretty sure though that I will only be able to hit one stud as the other leg will most likely not line up (although it is possible that the top cross piece might). Assuming I can only hit one stud, what's the best way to solidify the table/shelf (both would be metal)? I would think an anchor is not strong enough, but maybe if the other leg is snug against a stud would it be enough? What I want most is to have a very solid platform that won't sway/shake when the printer head is moving at high speeds.

Thanks for any insight!!

Comment: Pics would sure help you here...

Comment: Adjust the **acceleration** parameters on the printer's motion.

Comment: I cut up squares from an old neoprene mousepad and put one under each printer foot, which cut the noise and shaking down a lot. Adding a 2nd layer of mouse padding virtually killed the motion/noise. You can also attack a brick or block or dumbell to the top of the frame, drastically increasing it's moment of inertia and thus reducing the lateral frame displacements given a certain weight printhead moving at a certain speed. If you do attach to wall, do so in the line of the print head movement, the bed itself is usually too low to cause frame jerk, whereas the head has mechanical advantage.

Answer (score 2):

One stud may suffice. Or you can do something like attaching a piece that spans the back of the cabinet and is wide enough to span two studs and screwing that to the wall

Or you can just not worry about it; a bit of shaking isn't going to do much harm, and coupling it through the wall may make it louder... but if it's bothering you, I'd say it's worth the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Same as mounting a TV or towel bar:

- Wood screwed into two studs
- Printer stand screwed into wood

Wood can be dimensional lumber or plywood.

Comment: Or put the printer on the floor.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you read up on mass and inertia.

In simplest therm if the table mass is higher than the printer, then the printer would not be able to move the table.

Even more simple, if the table top is a 2 or 3 inch thick granite (kitchen counter top) it will not vibrate.

Anchoring might work but only if you can use 2 studs

Comment: Where does one get 3 inch thick granite?  ...and  what type of humans are needed to install that?  I'm joking..but yeah a heavier table will stop the shaking.

Comment: @RMDman at cemetery